# WSO2 ESB-BAM server profile files

Tags: xml, registry, wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I added server profile in my ESB 4.8.1, and I want to find out, is it possible to get this profile in a file (becasue I can't find it and I want to do the same on other server without doing it in console). I read that it is stored in registry.
Streams in WSO2 CEP are also stored in registry, but there is a stream-definitions.xml file, where CEP while is starting check this file and loads streams. 
Is it possible to do the same in ESB with server profile BAM files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESB Bam server profiles are stored in the config registry under config -> bamServerProfile. You can download this config file using the registry browser.